# How to get the value of another condition before the previous condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

input

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,1)).round(2), columns = ['A'])
df['cond1'] =[True,False,False,False,True,False,False,True,False,True]
df['cond2'] =[False,False,True,False,False,True,False,False,True,False]
df
```

My logic is like this

First get the position where `cond2` is true

Then find the position where `cond1` is true before `cond2` is true

Finally get the value of `A` column where `cond1` is true and assign it to the `expect` column

expected result table

```
    A       cond1   cond2   expect
0   0.42    TRUE    FALSE   
1   0.07    FALSE   FALSE   
2   0.99    FALSE   TRUE    
3   0.89    FALSE   FALSE   0.42
4   0.26    TRUE    FALSE   0.42
5   0.5     FALSE   TRUE    
6   0.85    FALSE   FALSE   0.26
7   0.07    TRUE    FALSE   0.26
8   0.97    FALSE   TRUE    
9   0.43    TRUE    FALSE   0.07
```

My solution is this

```
df['e1'] =df['A'].where(df['cond1']).ffill()
df['expect'] =df['e1'].where(df['cond2']).ffill().mask(df['cond2'])
```

output

```
A      cond1    cond2   e1      expect
0.72    TRUE    FALSE   0.72    
0.45    FALSE   FALSE   0.72    
0.16    FALSE   TRUE    0.72    
0.5     FALSE   FALSE   0.72    0.72
0.36    TRUE    FALSE   0.36    0.72
0.13    FALSE   TRUE    0.36    
0.93    FALSE   FALSE   0.36    0.36
0.68    TRUE    FALSE   0.68    0.36
0.83    FALSE   TRUE    0.68    
0.45    TRUE    FALSE   0.45    0.68
```

Is there a better way

Comment: Please clarify the question. In particular, what "before" and "previous" means. Ideally, provide an example of how you arrive at one entry in `expect`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and **ask a question**. Is this "expected result table" the output that you want, or the input? Please make sure you show both, explain the reasoning, and explain *why you are stuck* with implementing it. What do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? What part can't you do?

Comment: Did you mean Value(n, expect) = Value(n-2, A) where Value(n-1, cond2) is True and Value(n-2, cond1) is True? I see Row 6 and Row 9 match the condition, but Row 3, Row 4 and Row 7 offend…

Comment: I want to find the position where cond2 is true, and then find the value of A when cond1 is true above this position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the same logic with `shift` and `ffill`

```
df.loc[(~df['cond2']) & (df['cond2'].cummax()),'expect'] = df['A'].where(df['cond1']).ffill().shift().mask(df.cond2)
df
Out[249]: 
      A  cond1  cond2  expect
0  0.42   True  False     NaN
1  0.07  False  False     NaN
2  0.99  False   True     NaN
3  0.89  False  False    0.42
4  0.26   True  False    0.42
5  0.50  False   True     NaN
6  0.85  False  False    0.26
7  0.07   True  False    0.26
8  0.97  False   True     NaN
9  0.43   True  False    0.07
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
df.loc[(df.cond2.cumsum() > 0) & ~df.cond2, 'expect'] = df.A.mask(~df.cond1).ffill().shift()
```

Explanation:

- take value of column `A` for rows that have `cond1` value of True and propagate values forward to fill `NaN` rows, then shift these values down a row
- use these values to update only those rows that (1) have above them at least one `cond2` value that is True and (2) don't have `cond2` value of True